# Wasting of calculated hashes

Tags: mining-reward

If I am trying to find a nonce and in the meantime someone finds a nonce and adds a new block to chain, then will my work be wasted or it could be useful in finding other nonces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is wasted because the mining/hashing prodecure must contain **the hash of the previous block**. If someone hashes the block before you do it, you have to take the hash of the other person's block and put it in your block-header and hash it with the other header-information and then, the result is completly different.

In general, you check wheather the hash of the header is < the expected hash. If it is not, you forget your result because it's useless then.

Answer (score 1):

your work is "wasted" caused by the mining-algorithm.

you have found a new block if `sha2(sha2(blockheaderOfnewBlock)` starts with a certain amount of zeros. the blockheader contains a nonce, the hash of the previous block and some other information. since the previous-block-hash is another hash if a new block was found you have another information-base for your mining-software.

Answer (score 1):

It is "wasted". All block hashes calculated in the mining process are completely independent of each other. It is effectively random guessing; there is no progress that is being made and finding a hash does not make it more likely that the next one is a valid block hash. They are independent trials and each one is useless for calculating the next hash. So any hash that is not a valid block hash is "wasted".